# Application crash: QAcessibleInterface and segmentation fault

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault, qtgui, osx-elcapitan

I have this application bundled on Os X 10.11 El Capitan  with Qt 5.5, and runs justfine on the development machine. It also works on Os X Yosemite 10.10.5. The app crashes on all other machines that have Os X 10.11 El Capitan. Here is part of the Error log:

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
__TEXT                 000000010acca000-000000010b06b000 [ 3716K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Volumes/VOLUME/WaveAnalyser.app/Contents/MacOS/WaveAnalyser

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtGui                           0x000000010b83bc9a QAccessible::uniqueId(QAccessibleInterface*) + 106
1   libqcocoa.dylib                 0x000000010e73b961 QCocoaAccessibility::notifyAccessibilityUpdate(QAccessibleEvent*) + 17
2   QtWidgets                       0x000000010b3dac5f QAbstractItemViewPrivate::_q_rowsInserted(QModelIndex const&, int, int) + 127
3   QtWidgets                       0x000000010b3dce36 QAbstractItemView::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) + 1510
4   QtCore                          0x000000010bf0ac26 QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) + 2550
5   QtCore                          0x000000010bf80d2e QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted(QModelIndex const&, int, int, QAbstractItemModel::QPrivateSignal) + 78
6   QtCore                          0x000000010be8eea0 QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows() + 80
7   QtGui                           0x000000010baffb07 QStandardItemModelPrivate::rowsInserted(QStandardItem*, int, int) + 151
8   QtGui                           0x000000010baffec6 QStandardItemPrivate::insertRows(int, int, QList<QStandardItem*> const&) + 934
9   QtGui                           0x000000010bb0351b QStandardItemModel::appendRow(QList<QStandardItem*> const&) + 75
```

The problem shows up when I press the pushbutton that closes the `QMainWindow`. I can provide complete log to track down the problem.